# F# query expressions - Why am I getting this type comparison error?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have the following block of code:

```
let rec Sieve p nums =
    let filtered = query { for n in nums do 
                            where (n % p = 0 && n <> p)
                            select n } |> Seq.toList
    if filtered = nums then filtered       // Error
    else
        let nextIndex = 1 + (filtered |> List.findIndex (fun x -> x = p))
        if nextIndex > filtered.Length then filtered
        else
            let next = filtered.[nextIndex]
            Sieve next filtered
```

When I compile this, I get '**The type ''a list' is not compatible with 'System.Linq.IQueryable<'a>**'. On the line that I've marked with the comment error.

I've found that If I add a type annotation to Sieve for nums to make it (nums: int list), it will then work correctly. But, If I replace nums on the line

```
if filtered = nums then filtered
```

with:

```
if filtered = [1..10] then filtered
```

Then I get the same error referring to filtered on the line:

```
Sieve next filtered
```

Since when I get filtered I convert it straight to a List before using it, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a confusing behavior of the type checker.

If type of `nums` isn't known beforehand (as in your example), the type checker looks at first use of `nums` in `query` block and infers it as `IQueryable<'a>`. Since F# List doesn't implement `IQueryable` interface, unification between `'a list` and `IQueryable<'a>` fails.

If you specify type of `nums` as `'a list` in declaration, the use of `nums` in `for n in nums do` looks like a normal use of `IEnumerable` collections.

That said you're using a wrong tool for the job. Query expressions are meant to be used for handling external data sources. In-memory queries should be facilitated by sequence expressions:

```
let filtered = seq { for n in nums do 
                        if n % p = 0 && n <> p then
                             yield n } |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: I'm just playing around trying out some of the new language features, wouldn't normally do it this way :)